# call java methods from QTP/vbscript

Tags: java, vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

I am working on a Java application which has a custom build java tree, which QTP though able to identify, but not able to use JavaTable methods such as GetCellData.

In order to fetch cell data I did some googling and came to know if I am able to directly call the Java method which in my case is getDisplayedtextAt(int, int) then I am able to achieve the task.

Does anyone have any idea how can I make a call from QTP to Java methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Every Java test object has a `getStatics` method**, about which the QTP documentation says:

> Returns the Java object capable of accessing static members (methods
>   and fields) of the specified Java class.

**Also, `JavaTestObject.Object` gives you the native Java (not Windows!) GUI class object instance** of the GUI control` that the test object represents.

One of those two pathes are the way to go to call your `getDisplayedtextAt` method.